# Is there smart casting in Guild Wars 2?

Tags: guild-wars-2

There are two main games I play. League of Legends and Guild Wars 2. I really like the smart cast functionality that League of Legends have. It increases the efficiency of my control over how I cast my spells and generally improves my game-play and enjoyment of the game.

Is there a similar functionality in Guild Wars 2? There are many different spells that require me to click once to show the target selection of the spell and then once again to aim my spell. I would like to just click once on my spell and have it cast where my mouse is hovering over.

Answer (score 5):

Yes there is. Equivalent to the QWER buttons in League of Legends, you have the 12345678 buttons in Guild Wars (since you probably use WASD to move the character) as standard keybinding to your skills.

Those keybindings can easily be changed here (you can change it even to your mouse buttons):

[image]

Additionally, for Guild Wars 1, the same applies.

When you want to smartcast the abilities, you have to switch an option in your settings.

You can find the checkbox in the settings screen (accessed by pressing F11);

[image]

Watch the following video to see how it is done;